# Tiny question about closure of javascript

Tags: javascript, closures

I want to change the element's width in order to do a simple animation
here's the code:

```
function mysildeDown(elem) {
    var fullw = parseInt(getStyle(elem, 'width'));

    elem.style['width'] = 0;

    for (var j=0; j < 100; j++) {
        (function () {
            **var i=j;**
            setTimeout(function () {
                elem.style['width'] = (i / 100) * fullw + 'px';
            }, (i + 1) * 10 );
        })();
    }
}
```

//the GetStyle function is no problem
I wonder why should I use var i=j ,Thanks a lot

Comment: Firing 100 timeouts is not an optimal way to do animations. You could use a timeout recursion: an initial timeout triggers more timeouts until the animation target is reached.

Comment: I sense you are reading John Resig's book "Pro JavaScript Techniques".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally when doing something like this inside of a loop, and using the value of j in another function, the function always ends up with the last value of j. So, you need to find a way to use the value of j as it was when you created that function inside the loop.

The way I normally see is to pass it in as a parameter in the immediately invoked function as below.

```
function mysildeDown(elem){
  var fullw=parseInt(getStyle(elem,'width'));

  elem.style['width']=0;
  for(var j=0;j<100;j++){
    (function(i){
      setTimeout(function(){
        elem.style['width']= (i/100)*fullw+'px';
      },(i+1)*10)
    })(j);
  }
}
```

Comment: There shouldn't be any need to pass it into your anonymous function.  j will be in scope.

Comment: is there any downside to passing it in, versus setting the i variable within the function as Lanston did originally? Just curious.

Comment: @Endophage, you're missing the point. The timeout functions will be bound to variable `i`, whose value will end up being the last value of `j` (99). You need to bind different values to each timeout function so that the desired animation can be achieved.

Comment: it's not a downside: It simply won't work. Your answer addresses this problem.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I normally do it this way when setting event handlers, but wasn't sure if the setTimeout would function differently.

Answer (score 0):

using the `var` keyword when defining a variable in javascript declares it within the scope of the current line of code.  In your specific case, if you didn't use the `var` keyword when declaring variable `i` then `i` would be global, potentially causing problems as it's so commonly used in `for` loops.

By using the `var` keyword, inside a function, your variable `i` is local to the function and is not accessible outside the scope of that function.

There is some good info [here](http://www.mredkj.com/tutorials/reference_js_intro_ex.html).

Answer (score 0):

So that i will have the value of j within the timer function at the time setTimeout was called.  Essentially, you are storing the value of j to be used when the timer fires.